# How to get new JWT access token from refresh token in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I am using JWT with node.js and React for a web application and have the following setup for my JWT:

1. At login, users get two httpOnly cookies with one access token (expires in 5 min) and one refresh token (expires in 7 days). The refresh token is also saved in DB for safety and later used when we will get a new access token.
2. The access token is verified for each request.
3. When the access token has expired, we will get a new one with the refresh token, but here I want to know how to setup this correctly and secure.

So my question is, when the access token has expired, how will I create a new one with the refresh token?

I use this authentication check on each api route to validate the access token, should I make an if statement here that says "if (err)..." and do the validation on the refresh token and send out a new refresh token here?

```
function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
 if (req.cookies.Accesstoken == null) return res.sendStatus(401)
 const token = req.cookies.Accesstoken
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403) //Validate the refresh token here and make new refresh token?
    next()
  })
}
```

Or is this a bad idea? It feels like if I'm doing this the only really useful thing with the Access token is that I don't have to hit the database for each request..

How should I implement this?

Comment: "The refresh token is also saved in DB for safety" --- you don't need JWT then, use a random string instead.

Comment: Ok, but I use JWT for the access token which is not stored in the DB (so I don’t have to hit the DB every time). So my question is when should I check for the refresh token? Is my example above a god way to do it?